# If the median AM of a triangle ABC bisects the angle $\hat{A}$, then the triangle is an isosceles.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Can we solve the above problem using only the criteria for congruent triangles (i.e., without using the fact that the sum of the angles of a triangle is $180^\circ$)?

Comment: Are you able to use transversals?

Comment: @S.Sharma, that would be equivalent to using the Fifth Postulate, i.e. to using the fact that internal angles sum to $180°$ (equivalent to the postulate itself), whereras OP requires basically not to base demonstration on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most basic approach, I believe. Consider the triangle $\triangle ABC$, in which $AD$ is both median and bisector.

1. Extend $CD$ to a segment $DC'\cong CD$.
2. Then $\triangle ACD \cong \triangle BDC'$ by SAS criterion.
3. Consequently you have $\angle BC'D \cong \angle ACD$ and $AC \cong BC'$.
4. For transitivity then $\angle BC'D \cong \angle BCD$.
5. Thus $\triangle BCC'$ is isosceles and $BC \cong BC'$.
6. But from transitivity and point 3. then $BC \cong AC$ and $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I liked all the proofs, but I think this one is the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If we have a $\triangle ABC$ with a point $M$ on $BC$, and $\angle A$ is bisected by $AM$, then we obtain $\angle BAM \cong \angle CAM$ and the 2 new triangles $\triangle BAM$ and $\triangle CAM$. Now, draw a line segment $PQ$ through $A$ parallel to $BC$. Then, draw line segments $PB$ and $QC$ perpendicular to $PQ$.

Now, due to the alternate interior angles theorem, $\angle BAM \cong \angle PBA$ and $\angle CAM \cong \angle ACQ$. Now, $\angle ACQ + \angle ACM = 90$ and $\angle PBA + \angle BAM = 90$.

I think from here the pieces should fit. Though if you have issues drawing the picture, I can provide one. Also, I wasn't sure whether you could use transversals or not, but considering how most geometry textbooks are, I assumed that perhaps you could.

Comment: Thank you, but I am still unable to solve it with what I have in hand. I should clarify that this is a problem (in a book I am reading) that appears before any mention of parallel lines or rectangles. So, the only tools I have to solve it is the criteria for deciding when two triangles are congruent.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I'll see if I can edit my answer.

Comment: Can you only use ASA, SAS, HL, etc?

Comment: @Sumac Correct. The proof you need **does not** depend on the Fifth postulate, from which all the Theorems on parallel lines and the interior angles Theorem depend.

Answer (score 0):

From M, drop perpendiculars AP and AQ to AB and AC respectively. Then,

by AAS, $\triangle APM \cong \triangle AQM$.

[If AAS is not allowed, try reflect M about AB to H and reflect M about AC to K. Note that $\triangle AHM \cong \triangle AKM$.]

[image]

Go on to prove $\triangle BPM \cong \triangle CQM$ using RHS.

[If RHS is not allowed, try BPM and CQM are two equal circles. $\angle B$ will be equal to $\angle C$ because of equal chords on equal circles.]

As a result, $\angle B = \angle C$.

Comment: The problem is that I only have SAS, SSS and ASA as my criteria. AAS follows from ASA using the fact that a triangle has sum of angles $180^\circ$. Is there a way to get AAS without using that fact or complete your proof without using it?

Comment: @Sumac That means RHS cannot be used also?

Comment: Yes. It should be solvable without it (unless it follows from the other criteria).

Comment: @Sumac See comments in square brackets.

Comment: @Sumac see the second part of the proposition http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI26.html

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD$ be a median and a bisector of $\Delta ABC$ and $E\in AD$ such that $D$ be a midpoint of $AE$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle ADC=\measuredangle BDE,$ we obtain:
$$\Delta ADC\cong \Delta EDB,$$ which gives
$$BE=CA$$ and since
$$\measuredangle BAD=\measuredangle CAD=\measuredangle BED,$$ we obtain $$AB=BE,$$ $$AB=AC$$ and we are done!